# if and else condition alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a js condition that is working but am wondering if there is a better way to do this. My code checks if user is NOT loggedin and then hides a togglable mobile menu.

The mobile menu works as needed via media query. But I have one additional caveat, I don't want it to show if the user is not logged in thus my code below.

```
               if (acs.user.loggedin == false) {
                  $( "a.navbar-toggle.icon" ).hide();
                  $( "#my-menu" ).show();
                }
```

Works well except if the user logs out after the page is rendered. The `acs.user.loggedin` is an object from an api so I cant really touch it. I have to do everything on my end. Let me know if there is something I can do

Comment: Hiding/showing elements based on a client side javascript is generally relatively insecure and often better done with a server side script. With that said, can you not simply refresh the page on logout, or redirect them to another page after logout? If not, then can you not add a hide/show in the logout method you're calling?

Comment: @Dave Goten: you have a list of comments. Only author can change their comments. You hide the "edit" button with JS. It's **not** insecure, since the `edit` endpoint is known anyway.

Comment: @DaveGoten I can't touch the api, the logout link only works without refreshing the page.  I was hoping there is a way to check if acs.user.loggedin changed and then create an action

Comment: @nolawipetros Without a callback or some sort of state changed method on the asc object, this can be a bit tough. But if your button/link is simply something like `<button onclick="logout()" />` you should be able to at least do `<button onclick="logout(); toggleMenu();" />` Where `toggleMenu()` contains the code you have above. Failing that, how about setting an interval to check logged in status regularly. If the logged in status changes to false do the hide? Otherwise do nothing. Start the interval when the page loads and have it check every x milliseconds? Not ideal though... @zerkms sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using forced refresh! Basically refresh the page on logout so that I the proper display is shown. via @daveguten

Answer (score -4):

You can use the switch statement

```
switch(acs.user.loggedin){

    case false: $( "a.navbar-toggle.icon" ).hide();
                      $( "#my-menu" ).show();
                   break;


    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why downvoting?

Comment: Please provide some rationale behind your answer. "if there is a better way to do this" --- why do you think one should prefer writing it in this way

Comment: The problem he sees is actually larger than this. His "solution" is completely insecure if that's done using Javascript (which is client side). A good solution should be one giving him a server-side example.

Comment: @AlejandroIván "is completely insecure" --- it's not entirely correct. It's perfectly valid to hide elements on a page based on some conditions.

Comment: @zerkms that's true. I should have said "potentially insecure".

Comment: @zerkms the title says "alternative" not better

Comment: @cssGEEK the question consists of not only title but the question body itself.